# Why is the button graphic only displaying on the most recent JavaFX page? Are duplicate controllers not independent of each other?

Tags: java, svg, javafx

I've simplified the idea for the sake of explanation:

I have an MDI application. There's a button, when you press it, it will open a new Window within that MDI application. If you press the button again, yet another duplicate of that window will open. The window has Buttons, those buttons have graphics (SVG's). The graphics display correctly, but when I open a new Window the graphics will no longer display on the new Window and only on the most recently opened Window.

I'm sure this will not only be a concern here, but will be an issue for all functionality across various Windows of the same type. Why is this happened?

BTW: libraries are JFoenix and JFXtras

```
/* this will be called when the button is pressed to open a new window. mdiCenter is the anchor pane the windows are displayed on */

public void addWindow() throws IOException 
{
    try
    {
        BorderPane pane = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("MyPage.fxml"));
        pane.setMinSize(400, 300);
        Window window = new Window();
        window.getContentPane().getChildren().add(pane);
        mdiCenter.getChildren().add(window);
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/* this method is called when MyPage is initialized */
private void setButtonSvgs()
{
    double size = 20;
    String style = "-fx-background-color: white;";

    button1.setGraphic(Util.getGlyph("SVGname", size, style));
    button2.setGraphic(Util.getGlyph("SVGname", size, style));
    button3.setGraphic(Util.getGlyph("SVGname", size, style));
    button4.setGraphic(Util.getGlyph("SVGname", size, style));
}

/* the following are in the Util class. this is the method that's called in the method above ^ */

private static final List<SVGGlyph> glyphs = SVGGlyphLoader.getAllGlyphsIDs().stream().map(item -> SVGGlyphLoader.getIcoMoonGlyph(item)).collect(Collectors.toList());

public static SVGGlyph getGlyph(String name, double size, String style)
{
    for (SVGGlyph glyph : glyphs)
    {
        if (glyph.getName().equals(name))
        {
            glyph.setSize(size, size);
            glyph.setStyle(style);
            return glyph;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

/* the SVG glyph list is initialized in the main application but I'm not sure that's relevant. */
```

Please help! I don't know why this is happening! Every time an FXML is loaded, shouldn't a new controller be instantiated and be independent of the others?

Comment: Be carefull here that you are calling a static method so no new Controller is created every time.That's something Javadoc not claiming clearly...If you want a new Controller to be created every time you have to use a `non static ` load() method.Actually i think from 8 load() methods the 2 first are non static.You can check by decompiling FXMLLoader class. If you don't catched it i will add an answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. In my Utility class, the glyphs list and getGlyph methods are static. By making these non-static it solved the problem. A singleton Utility class will be the solution.

Comment: Nope, it won't. Making the methods/list non-static just removed the "symptoms". If you use the singleton pattern, you'll get the same issue.

Comment: Yes I just discovered this when trying to implement. Makes sense. Unfortunately I'm just going to have to re instantiate a new instance each time.

Answer (score 0):

> The  `FXMLLoader`  class lets you set a controller for the root element
>   in the code using the  `setController()`  method. Use the 
>   `getController()`  method to get the reference of the controller from 
>   the loader. Developers make a common mistake in getting the reference
>   of the controller. The mistake  is made because of the way the  load()
>   method is designed. There are seven overloaded versions of the  load()
>   method: two of them are instance methods and five are static methods.
>   To use the  getController() method, you must create an object of the 
>   `FXMLLoader`  class and make sure that you use one of the instance 
>   methods of the class to load the document:

---

**All load methods existing in JavaFX,found decompiling `FXMLLoader`(from JavaFX 8) class:**

Non static:

```
 @CallerSensitive
 public <T> T load() throws IOException { .. }

 @CallerSensitive
 public <T> T load(InputStream arg0) throws IOException { ... }
```

Static:

```
 @CallerSensitive
 public static <T> T load(URL arg) throws IOException { ...}

 @CallerSensitive
 public static <T> T load(URL arg, ResourceBundle arg0) throws IOException { ... }

 @CallerSensitive 
 public static <T> T load(URL arg, ResourceBundle arg0, BuilderFactory arg1) throws IOException { ... }

 @CallerSensitive
 public static <T> T load(URL arg, ResourceBundle arg0, BuilderFactory arg1, Callback<Class<?>, Object> arg2)
            throws IOException { ... }

 @CallerSensitive
 public static <T> T load(URL arg, ResourceBundle arg0, BuilderFactory arg1, Callback<Class<?>, Object> arg2,
            Charset arg3) throws IOException { ...}
```

---

**Finally:**

Mention that you are using static methods,so your controller may getting the same instance of the `Nodes` you want to create.So that `Nodes` are removed from the original parent and are added to the new one...